# undefined reference to: dlopen, dlclose,

Tags: c++, linker

I have a program that run fine in Ubuntu 11.04 x86.
But know I'm compiling from Kubuntu 11.10 x64 and I get these errors in the linking process.

Its a codeblocks project and "-ldl" option is set.

I have also do a manual search and there is no libdl.a in the usr/lib folder.

Somebody knows how to install that library?

Comment: The `dl` library is part of the standard library, which is included in every installation. Try `ls /usr/lib/libdl*.so` instead to make sure nothing is wrong.

Comment: I suspect this has more to do with the x86 -> x64 switch than with the Ubuntu -> Kubuntu one. Also, your question would be better suited for http://askubuntu.com/.

Comment: ls /usr/lib/libdl*.so -> No results found.....

Comment: I am really getting bothered by how many valid topics are being closed, apparently just for the fun of it.

Answer (score 2):

perhaps you need the `libc6-dev` package. On  my Debian/Sid, the library is in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2`

Comment: Yes the file is there, but how can I add the file to the compiler?

Comment: On my Ubuntu 11.10 machine the libdl.so library is located in the /lib32 directory.